# Constantly update a .txt file with title of open application window?

Tags: windows, script, title-bar

Let's say I'm running a browser window and the title of the window is something like "Title Here - Mozilla Firefox." I want to constantly update a .txt file that contains the title of this window, meaning the .txt file should change as the title bar changes (doesn't have to be instant, maybe every 1 second).

I already know this is possible on Linux with `wmctrl` and a little scripting, but I would like to do this on Windows 10.

How can I go about making this? What applications or SDKs would I need?

**EDIT:** If anyone is curious to see the Powershell script I ended up with, [here you go](https://www.hastebin.com/ajesimosel.php). Save it as a .ps1 to run (and be sure to [enable Powershell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started using PowerShell. The code was adapted from a  [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/05/22/get-windowtitle-ps1/) and from a StackOverflow answer by Keith Hill. [See his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426993/run-a-batch-file-every-x-number-of-seconds-using-powershell) for parameter description.

`$period = [timespan]::FromSeconds(5)
$lastRunTime = [DateTime]::MinValue 
while (1)
{
    while ((Get-Date) - $lastRunTime -lt $period) { 
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
    $lastRunTime = Get-Date
    Get-Process |where {$_.MainWindowTitle} |format-table MainWindowTitle –AutoSize > c:\users\username\title.txt
}`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not the most elegant suggestion, but one that might work, especially if you are comfortable with creating scripts. [Macro Express Pro](https://www.macros.com/) is a program that works with Windows and has substantial features. The looping and logic controls within [Macro Express](https://www.macros.com/) are quite powerful. One of the features I discovered as part of this research is the ability to load a string variable with the current window's title bar.
https://www.macros.com/help/Index.htm
I used "title bar" as the search term and clicked on the Set String Variable entry. Scrolling down in the results shows:

> Set Value To Top Most Window Title
>
> Examines the window that is currently on top of all others, takes the
>   name that is in the caption bar (i.e. the Window Title) and places it
>   into a variable.

I lack the scripting skill to suggest how to process the string variable henceforth, as any actions would then change the window focus, but you may discover more flexibility than I in the overall program.